# Is there a name for having an obsessive interest in new topics for short periods of time?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, terminology

I have the tendency to get obsessively interested in a subject for 2 weeks, get bored, and then move on to something else.  For instance I have just started learning about chess and find myself extremely interested in it at the moment but know it will most likely pass soon.  In the last year I have looked at window farms, cooking, entrepreneurship (I started a muse business), tea, classic books (such as huckleberry Finn and Waldon), graphic novels... you get the idea!

The point is that most the time I do not find myself repeating the same topics again or express much interest towards them.  It might be more that I enjoy learning the topics but not going in depth.

I was wondering, is there a name for this tendency?  Is this a trait found more often in men than women?  I don't really find it a problem, if anything it is beneficial because it pushes me to learn new things.  But nonetheless I am curious if there is a name for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's great that you have this ability -- it's your "special power".

I don't believe there is a special term for "intense preoccupations with narrow subjects", but such behavior is a common, but not necessary, feature of [Asperger Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) or AD.

AD does occur more often in men than women. According to [this paper](http://www.jaacap.com/article/S0890-8567%2809%2961723-8/abstract), prevalence in men is between 2-4X greater than in women.

Comment: If you say I have a special power then I won't disagree! :)